# NestJs not working with VScode auto-attach

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, nestjs

I would like to use VScode `auto-attach` with `NestJs` but it's not working as expected.

When `auto-attach` is enable and I run the `npm run start:debug` I'm receiving the following error:

```
Cannot connect to runtime; make sure that runtime is in 'legacy' debug mode.
```

[image: vscode error]

Comment: I've seen this too. but nevertheless, debugging works for me and all debug points get hit. So I just ignore it for now. But it's annoying and I'd like to get rid of it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't a `NestJS` nor `VScode` issue.

The thing is that the project ran inside a `devcontainer` (docker). After setting up an environment that ran on the host I get the same behavior as Derryl Thomas commented on.

I still don't know why this is happening only inside a `devcontainer` (debugging using `ts-node` works) but due to outer issues as will regarding `devcontainer` I will tack a step back from using `devcontainer`.